Correctness of smaller cube function
For what range is this function I came up with to find the biggest cube smaller than integer n valid?
def smaller_cube(n):
    k = int(n**(1/3)) 
    return k**3 if k**3 < n else (k-1)**3

64**(1/3) == 3.99999... but the truncation works in this case, and if it were 4.00000...1 it would still work in the k-1 case.
I think it could go wrong if, for some large cube c, n > c**3 but n**(1/3) < c due to precision error, so would return c-1 instead of c. And for enormous values n**(1/3) will be completely off.
I'm also interested if int is replaced with round. Truncation of a number always rounds down, but rounding could round up to 0.5 up.


I think it could go wrong if, for some large cube c, n > c**3 but n**(1/3) < c due to precision error

This is not so hard to find. You'd choose n = c**3 + 1 for growing c until this scenario occurs. A little program to find it:
for c in range(1000000):
    n = c*c*c + 1
    res = smaller_cube(n)
    if res != n - 1:
        print(f"c={c}, n={n}, res={res}")
        break

Output:
c=84920, n=612392631488001, res=612370997523559

For round the results will be reliable for a greater range. Here it is harder to find the least c for which the result is wrong. It is somewhere in the order of 2.59e14. For example, c=259576414238729 and n=c**3+1 will lead to a wrong result.

We rely on smaller_cube being monotonic. How do you know it is?

Do you think the smallest wrong result will be n=cube+1? Are other n's too far away to cause truncation issues?

Yes, that is what I think. For the round version it is worth to also test with n=cube, and see if ever there was a wrong result. But I didn't find wrong results near c=259576414238729, but at more than three times that value.
